# Proving $R(3,4)\le 9$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-writing, ramsey-theory

I am trying to prove $R(3,4)\le 9$. This is my approach:

> For any $K_9$ we have (WLOG) at least 4 red edges by the pigeonhole
>   principle. Consider all of the edges between these 4 red edges, if any
>   of them are red, we have a red $K_3$. If this is not the case, all of
>   the edges between them are blue, forming a $K_4$.

Is this correct? Can anyone help me neaten up this argument?

Comment: The problem is asymmetric. You have dealt with the issue of red edges. But what if no vertex has as many as four red edges - how do you deal with that situation? There is a subtlety there, because you might like to use $R(3,3)=6$ - but can you guarantee six blue edges at a vertex to use it?

Comment: @MarkBennet can I not use the same argument and interchange red and blue?

Comment: Try using the same argument - $R(3,4)$ generally means a red $K_3$ or a blue $K_4$ (the way you have constructed it) you can't change the colours in the target configuration half way through - it is not enough to find or avoid a blue triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to expand on how you decided that there must be $4$ red edges, I think. And I don't really understand how you are using "WLOG" in this context.

If the four red edges are a cycle, or even a path, joining those associated vertices with blue edges will not form a blue $K_4$.

---

If you can find a vertex that connects with $4$ red edges, then those $4$ vertices either have a red connecting edge somewhere - forming a red $K_3$ - or they are all blue, forming a blue $K_4$.

If you can find a vertex that connects with $6$ blue edges, then the $K_6$ connected to it contains either a red triangle $K_3$ or a blue triangle, which with the initial blue-connected vertex forms a blue $K_4$.

So a vertex that connects with exactly $5$ blue edges and $3$ red edges is not suitable for initial consideration.

However, since $K_9$ has $36$ edges, there must be either $23$ blue edges or $14$ red edges, and each edge connects to $2$ vertices. This means that there are either $46\: (> 5\times 9)$ blue connections or $28\: (> 3\times 9)$ red connections. So there must be a vertex with one of the above required colour connections - $6$ blue edges or $4$ red edges - as required.

Answer (score 2):

another way of looking at it is if any vertex has blue degree greater equal to 6 or red degree greater equal to 4 we are done. since degree of each vertex is 8 the only case that we are left with is each vertex has blue degree 5 in which case the sum of all blue degrees is 45 which is odd and hence a contradiction. So we are done.