# Proof of familiarity between 9 people

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

How can we try to prove that among any 9  people thare are 3 people who are familiar with each other or 4 who are not familiar with each other?

**My approach:**

I try to convert this to graph theory. So I have a graph with 9 vertices which is clique. Now we try to point the graph edges into 2 colors. When we show that there always exist 3-clique or 4-clique in the same color in this graph then the statement will be proved. But how to start considering the graph?

Comment: Just a start.  If any person is familiar with four persons, and two of them are familiar with one another, we have three familiar people and we are done.  So none of the four are familiar, and we are also done.  Therefore, we may assume no person is familiar with more than three of the others.

Comment: This question can be rephrased in terms of a question about Ramsey Theory, asking to prove that $R(3,4)\leq 9$.  See the following: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748674/graph-theory-proof-that-r3-4-9), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408954/ramsey-theorem-r3-4-le-10-proof-why-is-the-number-of-friends-be-at-least-6?noredirect=1&lq=1), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286418/proving-r3-4-le-9?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Additionally, [plus.maths](https://plus.maths.org/content/friends-and-strangers) has a good proof of this halfway down the page.